# Is "with a sword" an adverbial of means or a postpositive attributive which modify "the enemy"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

```
"He killed the enemy with a sword."
```

Is "with a sword"  an adverbial of means or a postpositive attributive which modifies the enemy?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, he used the sword to kill the enemy.

Strictly speaking the other reading is possible, but I doubt anyone would read it that way.  "With a sword" fits very naturally with the verb *killed*, and "the enemy with a sword" is not especially common or natural as a noun phrase.  Instead, one might write "the enemy **that had a** sword".