# **At noon**—what it is modifying the verb "is" or the noun"Film"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, modifiers

> There is a film **at noon** we could see.

How to know what **at noon** modifies in this sentence?

Comment: I would say that it modifies the unspoken 'being shown' or 'starting'.

Comment: Are you asking to help you understand how to use similar expressions correctly, or are you more interested in linguistic structure for its own sake?

Comment: Were it written ***There is a film - "At Noon" - we could see.***, then without doubt it would be modifying "film".  It would be the name of the film. As it is, I believe @BillJ is on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *There is a film at noon we could see*.

"At noon" is not a modifier but a complement.

This is called an extended existential construction. It contains in addition to "there", "be", and the displaced subject, an extension, in this case the temporal expression "at noon" functioning as complement of "be".

Note that it cannot be omitted from the non-existential "A film is at noon".

Comment: Give me some links where i can learn more about this...

Comment: This may help: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=extended+existential&source=bl&ots=WSHKg4fqsZ&sig=ACfU3U15uNOIrSPj8F-WO2kYoGC9TiWg2g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOuIuasLj7AhVdTEEAHf2YDncQ6AF6BAgWEAM#v=onepage&q=extended%20existential&f=false)                  . Notice that additional items are given as extensions within the VP, not modifiers of the subject NP. In fact, extension may be adjuncts or complements, but in the your example the extension is a complement.

Answer (score 0):

It could be understood to modify either the verb "is" or the noun phrase "a film", as it is in the standard position for modifying either and both interpretations make sense. English is often ambiguous. (For example, see [Is "with a sword" an adverbial of means or a postpositive attributive which modify "the enemy"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15818/is-with-a-sword-an-adverbial-of-means-or-a-postpositive-attributive-which-modi)) In this case, it makes no practical difference.

Note that there are also other possible interpretations. For example, KB has suggested in a comment that some elements can be understood to have been omitted from the sentence.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say. It can't modify "noon" since "a film at noon" is not here a constituent. Temporal PPs can be modifiers in copula VPs as in "We were at that time very happy", but that's not the case here. Existential constructions may be either 'bare' or 'extended'. In this case. it's the latter kind where the temporal PP "at noon" is not a modifier at all but a complement of "be". Such extensions may also be locative, as in "There's one copy on the table", where the PP "on the table" is also a complement of "be".

Comment: @BillJ As usual, if you can show a practical reason why my answer doesn't work (it would impede understanding, it results in a contradiction, it's very rarely used relative to other interpretations, etc.), I'd certainly be willing to change it.

Comment: It's a complement because in the non-existential "A film is at noon", the temporal PP "at noon" cannot be omitted. The complement attributes are extended to the existential construction, so in "There is a film at noon ..." the temporal PP "at noon" is again a complement of "be" just as it is in the non-existential counterpart. Btw, the OP's question is about grammar, not semantics).

Comment: This may help: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=extended+existential&source=bl&ots=WSHKg4fqsZ&sig=ACfU3U15uNOIrSPj8F-WO2kYoGC9TiWg2g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOuIuasLj7AhVdTEEAHf2YDncQ6AF6BAgWEAM#v=onepage&q=extended%20existential&f=false).  Notice that additional items are given as extensions within the VP, not modifiers of the subject NP. In fact, extension may be adjuncts or complements, but in the OP's example the extension is a complement.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, you and I take different approaches to this sentence. I agree on that. I still don't see any reason why your approach is preferable. (In fact, it seems much more complicated than mine, which might be a strike against it.)

Comment: Because grammatically that's what "at noon" is, i.e. a temporal PP in clause structure, in this case a complement of "be". Look at the other examples given in the reference I gave you.

Comment: @BillJ I still don't see any particular advantage to H&P's method. If you do see it, I'd be happy to be enlightened. Otherwise, I'll let my answer stand.

Comment: It's not so much a case of 'advantage' but of of syntactic fact. It's obvious that "a film at noon" cannot here be a syntactic unit, a constituent, so the PP must be a dependent in clause structure, either an adjunct or a complement; in this case the latte, for the reason I gave in my second comment.

Comment: @BillJ I suppose that I just take a more practical approach then. As usual, I have no objection to other approaches that work, including yours.

Comment: And I think who cares what it is called? Can you use it and similar patterns in other utterances? I have no idea why my answer was downvoted. Anyway, anything with "when" is adverbial. And film can be replaced by any manner of nouns.

Answer (score -1):

**Telling time in English**:
The preposition "at" is used:

at 2:00 o'clock
at 7:00 o'clock
at noon
at midnight
at sunrise
at sunset

It can be considered a prepositional phrase like: at the house. And is adverbial.

[thoughtco.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-use-preposition-at-1211795#:%7E:text=The%20preposition%20%27at%27%20is%20used,when%20speaking%20about%20everyday%20life.)

- an [event] at [time]

BRITISH COUNCIL:

> When (time and dates)
> **Learn about time *adverbials* like at seven o'clock, in 1998, last Saturday and in five minutes** and do the exercises to practise using
> them.
>
> Level: **elementary**
>
> *We use phrases with prepositions as time adverbials*:
>
> **We use *at* with:**
>
> - clock times:   at seven o'clock,   at nine thirty, at fifteen hundred hours

[British Council_Adverbs regarding time](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/when-time-and-dates)

And from Wikipedia:

> Subcategories for adverbials
> Adjunct adverbials are the most often
> discussed class of adverbials, when discussing distribution in
> English.[10] Complement adverbials are also seen to display similar
> attributes as adjuncts. Distinguishing between these is a matter of
> the overt realization of the phrase and is discussed below. The most
> recognizable subcategories for adjunct adverbials would be.:
>
> **Time (answers the question 'When?')** She will be arriving **in a short time**.

So, "She will be arriving at six o'clock" is also a time adverbial.
[Adverbial phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase)

Comment: Beware of uninformed downvoters.